# What is HTTPHandler with regards to Python's urllib2 library?

Tags: python, http, urllib2, urllib

I am new to using pythons HTTP interaction libraries urllib and urllib2 and I am wondering what is an HTTPHandler and what is the purpose of using in the the following context?

```
http_handler  = urllib2.HTTPHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
https_handler = urllib2.HTTPSHandler(debuglevel=_debug)
```

Furthermore, what is an OpenerDirector? As can be shown here:

```
  opener = urllib2.OpenerDirector()
  opener.add_handler(http_handler)
  opener.add_handler(https_handler)
```

I have read the documentation for urllib2 but can't seem to understand the actual purpose of these measures

Libraries: [urllib](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib.html) & [urllib2](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html)

Comment: Are you aware of event handling concept? Also I'd recommend to add links to the libraries you mention so that one doesn't need to search for it.

Comment: @YakovL Yes I am aware of event handling but I still don't see the purpose of using an http handler

Answer (score 0):

[As you can see](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2.httphandler#urllib2.HTTPHandler.http_open), those "handlers" are just objects that get a request (or I'd say "request params") object and actually make an HTTP request. And [OpenerDirector](https://docs.python.org/2/library/urllib2.html?highlight=urllib2.httphandler#openerdirector-objects) is an object that creates handlers of `protocol_open`, `protocol_request` and other events. I think further reading of docs should clarify their purpose; or just start implementing what you need and then you realise why/if you need them.